# File Cache between AFNetworking 2.0 and Nginx

Tags: ios, json, caching, nginx, afnetworking

iOS client:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"host/json/demo.json"
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

             }];
```

Nginx conf on server:

```
location /json {
          alias    /var/www/json;
          expires 30s;
}
```

First time I run the app and get json data from server correctly, then I modify the demo.json on server, restart the app, I still get **old** json data(even 30 second later), but using CURL commend in terminal I can get  **new** json data.I delete the app and reinstall it then I get **new** json data.
Any problem with my conf or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `GET:parameters:success:failure` is always using cache by default, so I changed to use custom `AFHTTPRequestOperation` without cache, like this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL] mutableCopy];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your server's response to your GET request contains [cache-control HTTP headers](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html), causing the foundation URL loading system to cache your request.  See the [NSURLCache Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and [this NSHipster article about it](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/)) to learn more.

During debug, you could temporarily disable the cache:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                        diskCapacity:0
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

But this is *absolutely not recommended* for use in most production apps, since caching is very important to network performance on mobile devices.

If there are specific resources that should not be cached, the server should indicate these using the cache-control headers.